# How should I display hyperparameter sweeps graphically?

Tags: data-visualization, hyperparameter

I performed a hyperparameter sweep for a dense neural network. One variable was "model type" where one model has a certain number of layers and nodes per layer. There was 10 of these. I also swept across 3 different number-of-epochs, 2 different first-layer activation functions, and 4 batch-sizes. This leaves a total of 240 data points, each with their own corresponding validation set RMSE.

What is the best way to view this data? Using a 5-D plot consisting of X,Y,Z,color,opacity? I figure I could make a bunch of 2D or 3D plots, but it might get messy and I would have to average over the other variables, and there wouldn't be a sense of "absolute performance" like there would be if I plotted everything at once.

Is there a standard way for visualizing hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: I explained this in my question. Please read it

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems clear you meant an exhaustive grid search. I got focused on the rest of the question when I posted my comment.  :)